# How to access variable value from another class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have one class 'testOrder' in Kotlin having below snippet..

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "testOrder", cascade = [ CascadeType.ALL ], orphanRemoval = true)
    var or: OData? = null,

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "testOrder", cascade = [ CascadeType.ALL ], orphanRemoval = true)
    var ur: MutableList<UData>? = ArrayList(),
```

This UData class has

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "usr", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    var sCriteria: MutableSet<SCriteria>? = LinkedHashSet()
```

and OData class has

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "owr", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    var sCriteria: MutableSet<SCriteria>? = LinkedHashSet()
```

I want to access ur.SCriteria in ABC class..

I am using

```
val sCriterias = testOrder.owr?.sCriteria;
```

same is failing for UData..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have initialized testOrder class and also make sure that you have set sCriteria a value and is not empty.